# Using webNavigation.onCommitted to inject script into web page

Tags: javascript, html, browser, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to find a way to inject a script element, as soon as DOM is usable into the web page and before any other script is loaded, within my web extension.

I've attempted achieving this by using [webNavigation.onCommited event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/onCommitted)
which is supposed to be fired `when a navigation is committed. At least part of the new document has been received from the server and the browser has decided to switch to the new document.` (quoting the previously linked page).

The fact is that, by the time I'm injecting the script, the document has already been parsed and rendered by the browser, so the objects I want to reference from the web page perspective aren't defined yet.

I've tested on Firefox only, I do not care for other browsers support at the time being.

I've built a minimal, reproducible example. The whole source can be fetched [here](https://github.com/chuck-/webnavigation-test).

Basically, in the background script I register my event handler, which injects a content script to the "committed" tab:

```
browser.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(details => {
  browser.tabs.executeScript(
    details.tabId,
    {
      'file': 'inject.js',
      'runAt': 'document_start'
    })
  console.log(details)
})
```

In inject.js, I create a script element and attach it to the document root:

```
const script = document.createElement('script')
script.src = browser.runtime.getURL('script.js')
script.onload = () => {
  console.log('injected')
}

console.log('injecting')
document.documentElement.appendChild(script)

0
```

script.js is dead simple:

```
TEST=1
```

To test the extension, I've built yet another dead simple web page:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>
console.log('too late?', window.TEST ? 'no' : 'yes :\\')
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

I expect to see in the console a log line 'too late? no'. It always happens to be 'too late? yes :\', except few cases such as opening the web page for the first time, closing the tab containing the page and restoring it (CTRL + SHIFT + T). Refreshing the page (F5, CTRL + F5, whatever) always results in 'too late? yes :\'

Comment: Have you found a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think the problem might be the extensionType [`RunAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/extensionTypes/RunAt), rather than the time the committed event fires:

`"document_start": corresponds to loading. The DOM is still loading.`

This is the soonest that the script will be injected. So I assume there is no way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: when I'm calling executeScript, I'm calling it in the context of onCommited, not just anywhere. so, the dom is still loading, it's fine, i just need it to be less loaded it can be to inject the script before anything else.

there's no real documentation about how onCommited is related to DOM loading, it just happens before onDOMContentLoaded (which means that the DOM is actually ready) and on the web, searching "onComitted + inject script" yields results in this direction.

Comment: "in the context of onCommited": Sure, but even if there were another event earlier the `runAt` would still inject your script on `status==='loading'`, so I think the injection depends on the `runAt` rather than the committed event. But your are absolutely right about the docs being vague on the exact time of either of those 2. Maybe someone can clear things up on Mozilla's discourse forum: https://discourse.mozilla.org/ Good luck

Comment: I don't think I follow your reasoning. If I execute the script with `runAt` set to `document_start` but using `browser.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded`, DOM will be ready. It doesn't matter the `runAt` in this case. So, if `onCommited` is guaranteed to happen in a DOM state that isn't ready, but just as much ready to inject something in the page, it should work.
Anyway, thanks for pointing out mozilla's discourse forum, I didn't know about it

Comment: Sorry, then I misunderstood your question. Thought the injection of your script is being too late and that you were looking for a way to have it being the first script on a page. So if you'd find a webNavigation event that is firing at a time when DOM is being loaded but no page script executed yet, then it still wouldn't matter - because of `runAt`.

Comment: I think you're overweighting the semantics of `runAt` (and `document_start` more precisely). I already gave you an example of what I'm trying to say, I won't argue any further about this.

Comment: wasnt argueing. just trying to help. but a sieve won't hold water, so where is the point.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find a way to inject a script element, as soon as DOM is usable into the web page and before any other script is loaded, within my web extension.

Once DOM is usable, inline scripts have already loaded and remote scripts have already started loading. Use [content_scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts) to inject it at `"document_start"`

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["*://*.mozilla.org/*"],
    "js": ["inject.js"],
     "run_at": "document_start"
  }
]
```

In `"inject.js"` add [beforescriptexecute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/onbeforescriptexecute) listener e.g.: `document.addEventListener("beforescriptexecute", starting, true);` (only supported by Firefox)

Then, handle the scripts before it executes.

If you need to handle the DOM, then you would also need to add a listener for [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event) e.g.: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', doSomething);`

Comment: a static-defined content script in the manifest is not my ideal solution. anyway, in my example, the script I'm injecting is running at document_start, just a bit before DOMContentLoaded is triggered. Speaking of `beforescriptexecute`, am I able to delay scripts execution and inject one before using this event?